# Move columns A to E to new sheet and repeat. Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have slightly different data but same format in one excel sheet.
Each data set is 5 columns. The first data set is column A-E, the second data set is column F-J, all the way through to DID-DIH

What I would like to do is to extract these to either their individual sheets or individual workbooks

Is this possible? Perhaps using VBA code?

Sorry I am an amateur trying analyse a massive data set

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get started would be to hit the record macro button and copy the first columns manually. Then stop the recording and look in the VBA editor at the code produced. Wrap this in a loop and make the necessary changes to move columns etc. Have a go and post the code if you get stuck.